# status code 400 error in ios

Tags: ios, http-headers, nsurlsession

I'm using iOS 7, where I work with NSURLSession to connect with the server.
I have tried the following codes:

```
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration 
    defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:  
    defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: 
    [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://**********/api/Users"];
    NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     NSString * params    
    =@"FirstName=Aravind&LastName=India&WorkingEmailAddress=aravind@gmail.com";
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
    completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
   {
    NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
    if(error == nil)
        {
         NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: 
         NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);
        }

    }];
    [dataTask resume];
```

And the error I am getting is as follows:

```
     { status code: 400, headers {
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
"Content-Length" = 0;
Date = "Wed, 20 Nov 2013 05:05:39 GMT";
Expires = "-1";
Pragma = "no-cache";
Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
"X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
"X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
 } } (null)
 2013-11-20 10:35:39.723 SessionApp[27223:a0b] Data = .
```

I can't understand. What should I do to check the error? Please guide me, I am new to iOS.

Comment: You are sending empty parameter that could be reason you are getting 400 Bad Request Error !

Comment: sorry, i wrongly deleted that line, i'm sending params as like.  NSString * params =@"FirstName=Aravind&LastName=India&WorkingEmailAddress=aravind@gmail.com";

Comment: This is not the way of sending parameters to server, Its Mobile Development not web development.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are unaware of how to send Parameters request to Server. I would like you to have a look at this library and its examples. It would help you get out of this problem.

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Example for sending parameters

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar", @"baz": @[@"firstName", @"lastName", @"Email"]};
```

Comment: No interface declaring NSDictonary declares the selector dataUsingEncoding, what we have to use instead of it

Comment: Check the link, I provided you.

Answer (score 0):

As per server response, there is no content to post.

You can get idea through this [link](http://hayageek.com/ios-nsurlsession-example/)